telescope scan all files in the disk when excute find_files in Neovim
enter image description hereI currently move my focus to Neovim and have installed a lot of plugins. The most confusing one is telescope. Every time I tried to search for files in current working directory, it scans all files in my disk and display. I also use nvim-tree for as files explorer. How can I make it only scan files in open directories?
I have tried to enter a specific directory to see whether this helps telescope reduce its searching scope. However, after trying all keys listed by the nvim-tree, I still can't enter the specific directory and omit its parent directory.

Run nvim directory_of_interest (which is typically the root directory of the project you are working on) instead of running nvim with your home directory as the working directory.

it works, thank you. Can we also redirect the current working directory just by nvim-tree?

It does offer ways to do that, have a look at the documentation here:
https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-tree.lua/blob/master/doc/nvim-tree-lua.txt and search for tree.change_root to get started
